# Combine two prometheus queries and represent the result using Boolean

Tags: prometheus

Both of the following queries produce Boolean outputs.

Query1

```
state{token="59cdefc6f4e9ac94"}  1
```

Query2

```
state{token="c86fc1f35d479759"}  0
```

How to combine these two queries based on following logic? Thanks.

```
[Q1]&[Q2]
1  &  1  ->  1
1  &  0  ->  0
0  &  1  ->  0
0  &  0  ->  0
```

Comment: Your edit made existing answer incorrect, and this is against editing policies of SO. New version of question requires quite a bit different approach, thus it would be better to ask separate question. Plus. I recommend including other edge cases there: what should happen if q1 (or both) doesn't return anything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend this query:

```
state{token="59cdefc6f4e9ac94"} + on() state{token="c86fc1f35d479759"} == bool 2
```

Here:

- `+ on()` sums provided values ignoring any labels. Result doesn't contain any labels in the labelset,
- `== bool 2` returns one if LHS is equal to 2, and zero otherwise.

Please note that this query presumes that each query returns exactly one time series. If this is not the case and your queries might eventually return any other number of time series, I'd use

```
(
   vector(1)
   and on() (state{token="59cdefc6f4e9ac94"}==1)
   and on() (state{token="c86fc1f35d479759"}==1)
) or vector(0)
```

This query will return one if any of time series in both selectors is equal to 1, and zero otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your recommand; the first query has already resolved my issue. May I ask again, if the metrics of Q2 does not exist, is it possible to return only the result of Q1?